# How to modify a haplotype network plot created from the pegas package

Tags: r, plot

I've generated a network from a large set of fasta files. I've followed the instructions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755930/how-to-plot-pie-charts-in-haplonet-haplotype-networks-pegas). Although I've successfully plotted said network, there is allot of labels behind the pies. How can I disable these from appearing

```
plot(net, size = attr(net, "freq"), pie=ind.hap, fast = TRUE, legend=F, label=NULL, vertices.last=F)
legend('topleft', capitalize(colnames(ind.hap)), col=rainbow(ncol(ind.hap)), pch=20, cex=0.7)
```

[image: Network]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of other parameters that you seem to be aware of for that plot type, but the one you want is a logical:

```
label=False
```

You might also try

```
use.labels=False
```