# Change edge color, font color and tick color on Haplotype Network Plot in R

Tags: r, plot, bioconductor, phylogeny

Using the guide on:

[How to plot Pie charts in haploNet Haplotype Networks {pegas}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755930/how-to-plot-pie-charts-in-haplonet-haplotype-networks-pegas)

I was able to make a haplotype plot for my data. Here is my code:

```
library(ape)
library(plyr)
library(pegas)

## example.DNAbin is the DNAbin class object with the alignments 
d <- example.DNAbin
e <- dist.dna(d)
h <- pegas::haplotype(d)
h <- sort(h, what = "label")
(net <- pegas::haploNet(h))

ind.hap<-with(
  stack(setNames(attr(h, "index"), rownames(h))),
  table(hap=ind, pop=rownames(d)[values])
)

col.vec <- adjustcolor(rainbow(ncol(ind.hap)), alpha=0.4)

par(bg="white")
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))

plot(net, size=attr(net, "freq"), 
     scale.ratio=3.00, pie=ind.hap, bg=col.vec, fg="white")
title(main = "Haplotype Network Plot\n of Project AGBOU",
    line = -2.5, col.main= "black", cex.main=2)
```

This is the plot I obtained:

[image]

I would like to make the following changes:

1. Change color of edges (important)
2. Change color of ticks (important)
3. Change color of text inside circles (not very important)

I would like an image such as the one below:

[image]

I have not been able to figure out the parameters required for the plot command or the correct combination of functions to achieve this.

I'm hoping that someone here can help. Thanks.

Comment: Problem is partially solved. I can change some of the edge colors using the col.links options in the plot function.

i.e. plot(net, col.link = "red", ...)